# HTML5 Forms Action bahavior

Tags: html, forms

Okay I'm trying to pass parameters like this link here using form tag in HTML

https://pyramisaegypt.seebooking.com/#/booking-engine/room-list?property_id=445586&checkin=2018-11-22&checkout=2018-11-23&noOfAdults=1&noOfChildren=1&noOfRooms=1&promo_code=

but for some reason it always becomes this after i hit submit

https://pyramisaegypt.seebooking.com/?property_id=445586&checkin=2018-11-22&checkout=2018-11-23&noOfAdults=1&noOfChildren=1&noOfRooms=1&promo_code=#/booking-engine/room-list

Notice that whatever is after the hash and behind the question mark gets transferred at the end of the url

The page url is http://pyramisaegypt.com/test-page/

My code is

```html
<form id="reservation-widget-wrap-form-element" style="background-color: #f0f0f0; color: #777; padding: 10px; padding-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 20px;" action="https://pyramisaegypt.seebooking.com/#/booking-engine/room-list" method="get" target="_blank">

<div id="children-wrap" style="width: 20%; display: inline-block">
<div class="caption">Hotels</div>
<p><select id="reservation-widget-hotels" style="width: 100%;height: 32px;padding-left: 5px;margin-bottom: 0px;" name="property_id"><option value="547027">Pyramisa Cairo Suites Hotel</option><option value="568389">Pyramisa Sahl Hasheesh Resort</option><option value="31070">Pyramisa Sharm El Sheikh Resort</option><option value="35520">Pyramisa Isis Luxor Resort</option><option value="445586">Pyramisa Isis Island Aswan Resort</option><option value="450628">Pyramisa Isis Corniche Aswan Resort</option></select></p>
</div>

<div id="check-in-wrap" style="display: inline-block; /* background: white;">
<div class="caption">Check-in date</div>
<p><input id="reservation-widget-checkin" class="hasDatepicker" style="width: 125px;height: 50%;" name="checkin" type="date"></p>
</div>
<div id="check-out-wrap" style="display: inline-block; padding: 5px;">
<div class="caption">Check-out date</div>
<p><input id="reservation-widget-checkout" class="hasDatepicker" style="width: 125px;height: 50%;" name="checkout" type="date"></p>
</div>

<div id="adults-wrap" style="display: inline-block;">
<div class="caption">Adults</div>
<p style="width: 100px;"><select id="reservation-widget-adults" style="display: inline-block; width: 121.4px; height: 50%;" name="noOfAdults"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select></p>
</div>
<div id="children-wrap" style="display: inline-block;padding: 5px;width: 100px;">
<div class="caption">Children</div>
<p style="
    width: 100px;
"><select id="reservation-widget-children" style="display: inline-block; width: 121.4px; height: 50%;" name="noOfChildren"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select></p>
</div>

<div class="caption">Number of Rooms</div>
<p style="
    width: 100px;
"><select id="reservation-widget-children" style="display: inline-block; width: 121.4px; height: 50%;" name="noOfRooms"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select></p>
</div>

<div id="children-wrap" style="display: inline-block;padding: 5px;width: 100px; margin-left: 1%;">
<div class="caption">Promo Code</div>
<p style="width: 100px;">
<input type="text" style="width: 100%;" name="promo_code">
</p>
</div>

<p style="display: inline-block; width: 20%; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 2%;"><button id="submit-button" type="submit" style="
    background: #b01c30;
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 35px;
    border: none;
">Online Reservation</button></p>
</form>
```

i tried every solution out there to change the behavior of the hash in the action of the form but nothing seemed to be working so far.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look at how a URL is formed. Anything after a `#` is not sent to the server as it refers to an anchor on the page. Therefore a "GET" form will always strip out those bits.

Comment: It's a different URL than my website so I can't be sure but he uses /#/ as part of his structure, He is using Angular to do it and I can't seem to Manipulate my GET request to do as the required url

Comment: In which case, your only option is to catch the submission of the form with JS, build the appropriate URL in JS and set location in JS. This should get around the limitations you're experiencing